# Is there any event fires after $("#").load() is completed in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change some partial-view html code after the partial-view is loaded by this function

```
$("#myRootElement").load("MyAction?Parameter=" + value);
```

I saw inside the JQuery source code, there is a

```
$("#myRootElement").innerHtml = "MyPartialViewHtmlCode"
```

But I didn't find any event fires after this inner html is set. I want to fires a event after this here is what I have tried.

```
$("#myRootElement").on('load', function(){
  // My code.
})

$("#myRootElement").load('action?parameter=' + value);
```

It doesn't work at all. The break point never been hit.

Comment: Why not do it when the entire document is ready, a la $(document).ready?

Comment: jquery document https://api.jquery.com/load/  have callback function, try normal action like `console.log('message');` in call back function for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load provides a callback you can use

```
$("#myRootElement").load('action?parameter=' + value, function() {
  // load complete  do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you DP. And thank you everyone, I am crying about my foolish now.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [page](https://api.jquery.com/load/), there is a callback param.
Use like this

```
$("#myRootElement").load("MyAction?Parameter=" + value, function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```